# How to send thousands of objects via AJAX?

Tags: javascript, ajax, performance, jquery

I am trying to load 100K+ records into a cloud service using their AJAX API. It looks something like this:

```
var multiple = [{ "Author": "Sample Text" }, { "Author": "Second Sample Text" },...];

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'http://api.cloudservice.com/v1/your-api-key-here/Books',
    headers: { "Authorization": "Bearer your-access-token-here" },
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: JSON.stringify(multiple),
    success: function (data) {...},
    error: function (error) {...}
})
```

I do not want to send a payload of 100K records of course, so I can cut it down to a hundred at a time for example. Even so, doing this in a loop would still be large. How would I create reliable AJAX loop to do this or maybe another way? I also want to reliable record all the errors somehow too. Any experience or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why do you not want to send a payload of 100k records?

Comment: Some of the fields contain entire page contents, so the size of 100k records would end up as hundreds of MB's large. Timeouts would be my main concern.

Comment: Take a look a Javascript promises. Q.js is a nice implementation, but there are others as well.

Comment: You might just use Array#slice to break it up into whatever size chunk you like, executing $.ajax for each chunk. You shouldn't have to worry about limiting concurrent requests because your browser will throttle concurrent requests to the same endpoint.

Comment: Thx for the tip! Yes I prefer promises and am not really tied to using jQuery for handling the ajax part if there's a better alternative, ie q.js, amplifyjs, etc.

Comment: Do you want the ajax calls to be executed simultaneously or consecutively? I believe the reason to use promises would be to execute the calls simultaneously, whereas the answers that initiate the next ajax call in the success handler will execute them consecutively.

Comment: I would like to set it and forget it if possible and the quickest way for the data to be sent. I think concurrently would be better for that and I believe I would only have to worry about the resources of the workstation doing the AJAX calls, but reliability is most important (timeouts, browser crashes, etc).

Comment: Is this NodeJS, or are you just not concerned with having your access token in the javascript exposed to the public?

Comment: It's actually a cloud API service like Parse.com or Azure Mobile Services. So I do not have to worry about the server-side load. But no, not concerned about security because this is an internal app for admins.

Comment: for great-big stuff like this, i like to save my progress using localStorage so that i can resume from a browser tab crash. i don't store the data locally, just the counter/position info....

Comment: Good idea! Leveraging localStorage is brilliant despite the size limitation. I can keep the progress there like you mention and also store the errors!

Answer (score 0):

Recurse your list with the ajax calls breaking it up into sections of 100 (or whatever you set take to).

```
var multiple = [{ "Author": "Sample Text" }, { "Author": "Second Sample Text" }];
(function recursePost(set, iter, take){
 var group = iter + take < set.length ? iter + take: set.length - iter;
 var dataObj = [];
 for( var i = iter; i < group; i++ ){
  dataObj.push(set[i]);
 }
 iter += group;
 $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: 'http://api.cloudservice.com/v1/your-api-key-here/Books',
  headers: { "Authorization": "Bearer your-access-token-here" },
  contentType: "application/json",
  data: JSON.stringify(dataObj),
  success: function (data) {
    recursePost(set, iter, take);
  },
  error: function (error) {
    alert("Post Failed at " + (iter-group) + "-" + group);
  }
 });
})(multiple,0,100)
```

Comment: You think using AJAX's "complete" callback would be better? Also maybe promises would make this more elegant/reliable?

Comment: @TruMan1 - It is hard for me to tell since I cannot really mock that much data. If you feel one of those designs would fit better then that will work too :) I was just trying to outline the approach.

Answer (score 0):

Create a method that is called to send a batch of whatever size you need using the `slice` method on the array, call it manually once, then have your ajax return call it again if there are more records:

```
// obviously don't use globals in *your* code...
var current_count = 0;
var batch_size = 100;
var multiple = [{ "Author": "Sample Text" }, { "Author": "Second Sample Text" }... ];
var end_index = multiple.length() - 1;

function send_batch() {
   var batch_end = (current_count + batch_size) < end_index ? current_count + batch_size : end_index;
   var batch = multiple.slice(current_count, batch_end);
   current_count = batch_end;
   $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: 'http://api.cloudservice.com/v1/your-api-key-here/Books',
     headers: { "Authorization": "Bearer your-access-token-here" },
     contentType: "application/json",
     data: JSON.stringify(batch),
     success: function (data) {
        if (batch_end <= end_index) {
           send_batch();
        }
     },
     error: function (error) {...}
    });
};
```

You can pull out the Ajax call and parameterize things to make it more generic, but hopefully you'll get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't had a chance to test this, but you get the idea. Batching, sort of, but using the async instead of sync so you don't have to wait on the call back. You could do this in the recursive as well, but recursing in JS always takes more energy than a standard for loop.

```
var x=null, tempArr=[], batch_size = 100,
    multiple = [{ "Author": "Sample Text" }, { "Author": "Second Sample Text" }... ];

for(x in multiple){
  tempArr = (multiple.length > 100) ? multiple.slice(0,99):  multiple.slice(0,multiple.length-1);
  multiple = multiple.slice(100, multiple.length-1);
  if (multiple.hasOwnProperty(x){
    $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: 'http://api.cloudservice.com/v1/your-api-key-here/Books',
     headers: { "Authorization": "Bearer your-access-token-here" },
     contentType: "application/json",
     data: JSON.stringify(tempArr)
    })
    .done(function (data) {
      //process data returned
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make the ajax calls concurrently, you could to the following:

```
var BATCH_SIZE = 100,
    calls = [];
for (var i = 0; i < multiple.length; i += BATCH_SIZE) {
    var batch = multiple.slice(i, i + BATCH_SIZE);
    calls.push($.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'http://api.cloudservice.com/v1/your-api-key-here/Books',
        headers: { "Authorization": "Bearer your-access-token-here" },
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: JSON.stringify(batch)
    }));
}
$.when.apply($, calls).done(function () {
    alert('last call finished');
});
```

[**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Y4DAx/1/)